# Python - How to store class variables to array in defined order

Tags: python, arrays, class, variables

I have this simple Python code

```
class Person:
 name = ""
 surname = ""
 age = ""

def __init__(self):
  arr = #I want something like this ['name', 'surname', 'age']
```

How do I achieve putting that variables in order that I want (['name', 'surname', 'age']) to array? Without "initializing" them first with "self"? Thanks.

Edit: I need them in exact order how I defined them, not alphabetical order.

Comment: What is your use case, why you would do this?

Comment: You can use `vars(Person)` to inspect the namespace of the class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like the below with `__dict__`:

```
class Person:
    name = ""
    surname = ""
    age = ""

    def __init__(self):
        arr = [attr for attr in Person.__dict__ if ('_' not in attr) & (not callable(getattr(Person, attr)))]
        print(arr)

Person()
```

Output:

```
['name', 'surname', 'age']
```